# is possible to use password_hash() of php in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

table user have fields 'username' 'password' 'level'
field 'level' has two value 'student' and 'teacher'

when teacher insert student into table 'student' it trigger to insert into table 'user' too with value 
'new.username' 'password_hash(new.username,PASSWORD_DEFAULT)' 'student'

so the teacher just simply input student's data then it automatically create login data too for the student
student can login with username as 'username' and 'password', they can change the password after he/she log in

*note, password_hash() from http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: php server-side has that. Mysql doesn't. Architect it accordingly

Comment: so it is imposible? i have to insert via serverside right after the insert into 'stundent' success? aww,,,

Comment: or copy an existing hash. Or don't dupe up the data to begin with. Determine if you have an XY problem here or not.

Comment: which hashing algorithm used in php?

Comment: if default (bcypt), change mysql to mariadb and use this - https://github.com/ryancdotorg/mariadb-bcrypt-udf

Comment: @AlexMuravyov , i use password_default

Comment: @dan, if possible change mysql to mariadb - check link in my previous comment

Comment: the option to use `md5` is also there